# How to integrate Karate Framework with qTest

Tags: karate

My requirement is to once API test execution is completed, I need to update that result to qTest. qTest is providing API that can be invoked after test execution is completed but not sure how it can be invoke from Karate Framework through common code. Probably in TestRunner file general code can be written but not sure how to pass qTest test case id from feature file to TestRunner file. qTest is also providing SDK as well.

can someone please help me with this?

I have used Result class of Karate which is providing result details but not providing any metadata of from feature file.